# Storing my prime generator into an array

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I'm learning about arrays right now.

I made this short little program. It's a loop that tests then prints prime numbers. 
Specifically the numbers between 1 and 100.

I want to know if I can take my loop and store each prime number into an array. Here's my code:

```
public class QC3PrimeNumbers
{

    public static void main (String[] args)
   {
      System.out.println ("Here are the prime numbers: ");

       for (int index = 2; index < 100; index++)
      {
         if (index%2 != 0 && index%3 !=0)
         System.out.print (index + " ");         
      }

   }
}
```

Comment: This does not generates prime numbers. Fix your algorithm and to answer your question, you can use an `ArrayList` to store the prime numbers you found.

Comment: notice: arrays are fixed size.

Comment: Are you sure your test for prime number is correct? A prime number is a natural number greater than 1 that has no positive divisors other than 1 and itself. A natural number greater than 1 that is not a prime number is called a composite number.

Comment: What about index%5, index %7, and all nonmultiples of 2 and 3?

Comment: Herpity derpity derp. You guys are right. So I would have to add 5 and 7? Any other divisible numbers?

Arrays are fixed, but you don't need to fill them up, no?

Comment: @munchschair No this is false. The first and easiest way to implement this, is, for each number, test if between 2 and sqrt(number) this number is divisible. If no, this is a prime number. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use this condition: `if (index%2 != 0 && index%3 !=0)`, then it will never consider 2 or 3 prime numbers. Same thing if you changed it to:

```
 if (index%2 != 0 && index%3 !=0 && index%5 !=0 && index%7 !=0)
```

it won't find 2, 3, 5, or 7 to be prime numbers.

I corrected your algorithm and decided to use an [ArrrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) to store the list of prime numbers because the size is dynamic. Otherwise, we would first have to find the number of prime numbers in your region to determine the size of the array, and then do another loop of the same thing, except this time adding the numbers to the array.

Once you find a prime number. Use `nameOfArrayList.add(primeNumberFound);`.

***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__**

#### Do it with an ArrayList

```
public class QC3PrimeNumbers
{

    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println ("Here are the prime numbers: ");

        // use a List to store your prime numbers (its size is dynamic)
        List<Integer> primeNums = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        for (int index = 2; index < 100; index++)
        {
            boolean isPrime = true; // initially true, and reset this every loop

            // for every number that can factor into the index number
            for (int i = 2; i < index; i++) 
                // if a number is found that factors into it, it's not prime
                if (index%i == 0) isPrime = false; 

            if (isPrime) // if this current index number is prime
            {
                System.out.print (index + " "); 
                primeNums.add(index); // add it to the List
            }
        }
    }
}
```

***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__**

#### Do it with a regular Array

Here is how to do it using a regular array (not recommended, however):

```
public class QC3PrimeNumbers
{

    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println ("Here are the prime numbers: ");

        int numOfPrimes = 0; // counts the # of prime nums in your region

        // this loop will count up the number of prime numbers
        for (int index = 2; index < 100; index++)
        {
            boolean isPrime = true; // initially true, reset this every loop

            // for every number that can factor into the index number
            for (int i = 2; i < index; i++)
                // if a number is found that factors into it, it's not prime
                if (index % i == 0) isPrime = false;

            if (isPrime) // if this number is prime
                numOfPrimes++; // add it to the count
        }

        // array to hold the prime nums w/ size=how many prime nums we counted
        int[] primeNums = new int[numOfPrimes];

        int count = 0; // keep track of the position in the primeNums array

        for (int index = 2; index < 100; index++)
        {
            boolean isPrime = true; // initially true, reset this every loop

            // for every number that can factor into the index number
            for (int i = 2; i < index; i++)
                // if a number is found that factors into it, it's not prime
                if (index % i == 0) isPrime = false;

            if (isPrime) // if this number is prime
            {
                primeNums[count] = index; // add this prime num to the array
                count++; // change the array position tracker for next number
            }
        }

        for (int n : primeNums) // for every integer in primeNums array
           System.out.print(n + " "); // display that integer to the console
    }
}
```

Comment: The compiler is giving me two "cannot find symbol" errors pointing to list and array list. I'm using the first bit of code.

Comment: @munchschair try adding `import java.util.ArrayList;` and `import java.util.List;` to the top of your class.

Comment: Whoops! Now it run! IT LIVES

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;              
class numbers
{
public static void main(String args[])
{
    int[] prime=new int[20];
    int[] nonprime=new int[20];
    int count=0;
    int count1=0;`enter code here`
    try
        {
        InputStreamReader r=new InputStreamReader(System.in);  
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(r);  
        System.out.println("enter n value");
        int n=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        for(int i=1;i<n;i++)
        {   
            if(i%2!=0)
            {
                if(i%3!=0)
                    {
                    prime[count]=i;
                    count++;
                    }
            }
            else    
            {
            nonprime[count1]=i;
            count1++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("prime");
        for(int m=0;m<count;m++)
        {
            System.out.println(prime[m]);
        }
        System.out.println("Non-prime");
        for(int k=0;k<count1;k++)
        {
            System.out.println(nonprime[k]);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
}
```