# Program recognizing square numbers as primes

Tags: java, primes

I wrote a program to determine factors of a given number. At first it should of course check if the number is a prime number. This works, but if the number is a square number it recognizes it as a prime...

```
public class factors {
    public static void main (String [] args) {
        System.out.println("Enter the number you need factors of");
        int base = Kon.readInt();
        for (int i = 2; i < base; i++) {
           int a = base % i;
           if (a == 0) {
             break;
           }
           else {
             System.out.println(base+" is a prime number, so it has no factors");
             break;
           }
        }
        for (int i = 3; i < base; i++) {
            int res = base % i;
            if (res == 0) {
                int fac = base / i;
                System.out.println(i+" and "+fac+" are factors of "+base);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So if I enter 64, it says it's a prime, but then tells me that 8 and 8 are factors of 64 in the next line

Does anyone know what the problem might be?

Comment: It doesn't say 64 is a prime for me.  However, it does for 9, so see the answers below.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Determining Prime Numbers Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18625793/determining-prime-numbers-java) and [How to factor a number and determine whether its a prime number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18947244/how-to-factor-a-number-and-determine-whether-its-a-prime-number) and [Storing my prime generator into an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20020526/storing-my-prime-generator-into-an-array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you print it's a prime number **in** your loop, so that you pretend a number is a prime as soon as there's **at least one** value of `i` for which `base%i` is `0`.

You should check there's **no** value of `i` for which it's true. You might for example do this :

```
boolean hasFactor = false;
for (int i=2;i<base;i++) {
    int a=base%i;
    if (a==0) {
        hasFactor = true;
        break;
    }
}
if (!hasFactor){
    System.out.println(base+" is a prime number, so it has no factors");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that

```
if (a==0) {
    break;
} else {
    System.out.println(base+" is a prime number, so it has no factors");
    break;
}
```

will output that a number is not a prime the moment it's not divisible by `i` no matter what else, so you must first loop trough it completely before deciding it's not a prime.

So you want to change:

```
  for (int i=2;i<base;i++) {
      int a=base%i;
      if (a==0) {
        break;
      }
      else {
        System.out.println(base+" is a prime number, so it has no factors");
        break;
      } // end of if-else
    }
```

into:

```
  prime = true;
  for (int i=2;i<base;i++) {
      int a=base%i;
      if (a==0) {
        prime = false;
        break;
       }
    }
      if (prime){
        System.out.println(base+" is a prime number, so it has no factors");
      } // not a prime
```

Comment: This won't compile. Check your code.

Comment: This should fix it then...

Answer (score 0):

```
if (a == 0) {
    break;
}
else {
    System.out.println(base+" is a prime number, so it has no factors");
    break;
}
```

No matter what, you're breaking out of the loop on the first increment. Even if you removed the `break;` from the `else` block, you are still displaying whether or not the number is prime too early. You need to decide that *after* all of the iterations are completed.

So, consider a `boolean` variable to keep track of whether or not the number has at least one factor in it:

```
boolean isPrime = true; // true unless proven otherwise
for (int i = 2; i < base; i++) {
    int a = base % i;

    if (a == 0) {
        isPrime = false; // has factor so it's not prime
        break;
    }
}

if (isPrime) {
    System.out.println(base + " is a prime number, so it has no factors");
} else {
    System.out.println(base + " is a composite number: "); // say it's not prime

    // then display the factors
    for (int i = 3; i < base; i++) {
        int res = base % i;
        if (res == 0) {
            int fac = base / i;
            System.out.println(i + " and " + fac + " are factors of " + base);
        }
    }
}
```

[Here is a pastie to this entire class.](http://pastie.org/8604177)